# PySpark reading Avro file with a map complexe type. Exception while getting task result: java.io.InvalidClassException

Tags: python, apache-spark, avro

I would like to share my problem when I use the code from the example [avro_inputformat.py](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/examples/src/main/python/avro_inputformat.py)

```
schema = open('test_schema_without_map.avsc').read()
conf = {"avro.schema.input.key": reduce(lambda x, y: x + y, schema)}
avro_image_rdd = sc.newAPIHadoopFile(
    input_file,
    "org.apache.avro.mapreduce.AvroKeyInputFormat",
    "org.apache.avro.mapred.AvroKey",
    "org.apache.hadoop.io.NullWritable", 
keyConverter="org.apache.spark.examples.pythonconverters.AvroWrapperToJavaConverter",
    conf=conf
)

output = avro_image_rdd.map(lambda x: x[0]).collect()
for k in output:
    print "Image filename : %s" % k
```

and when running

```
spark-submit --driver-class-path /opt/spark-1.6.1/lib/spark-examples-1.6.1-hadoop2.6.0.jar read_test_avro_file_with_map.py
```

I get the following error

```
Job aborted due to stage failure: Exception while getting task result: java.io.InvalidClassException: scala.collection.convert.Wrappers$MutableMapWrapper; no valid constructor
```

when reading an avro file with the following schema:

```
{
"namespace": "test.avro",
"type": "record",
"name": "TestImage",
"fields": [
    {"name": "filename", "type": "string"},
    {"name": "data", "type": "bytes"},
    {"name": "metadata", "type":
        {
            "type": "map", "values": "string"
        }
    }
   ],
}
```

However, the same code works without problem when the schema does not contain the 'map' avro complex type :

```
{
"namespace": "test.avro",
"type": "record",
"name": "TestImage",
"fields": [
    {"name": "filename", "type": "string"},
    {"name": "data", "type": "bytes"},
   ],
}
```

If somebody knows where is the problem, please share your experience...

---

Versions:

- spark 1.6.1
- avro 1.8.0

The content of the avro file is :

```
records = [
{
    "filename": "input_filename_1",
    "metadata": {"a": "1", "b": "23"},
    "data": "1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0"
},
{
    "filename": "input_filename_2",
    "metadata": {"c": "11", "d": "213"},
    "data": "10,11,12,13,14,15"
}
]
```